# Python open file- dont you need full path to the file?

Tags: python, file, filepath

Every example I see about opening a file in Python has something like this:

```
myFile = open('somefilenamehere', 'r')
```

It never works for me when I just type the file name...you should always put full directory path where that file is

```
myFile = open('C:\\blah\\blah\\somefilenamehere', 'r')
```

Does it work for someone? I mean just putting the name of the file?

Comment: Yes. Python scripts have a current working directory. If the file you're trying to open is in the current working directory, then it'll work, if not, you need to give the path to it (be it relative or absolute). You can also change your current working directory using the `os` module.

Comment: If your `Python file (*.py)` and the `file to be opened` are in same directory, it will work.

Comment: @PrerakSola that's not precise. The process working directory is not always (and very often is not) the same as the script file directory.

Comment: It's obviously not working, but since our paths differ, there is no point to even try to give paths.

Comment: As a side-note, if you need to specify Windows paths in your scripts, I suggest you to use [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-14) to specify pathnames, e.g. `myFile = open(r'C:\blah\blah\somefilenamehere', 'r')`.

Answer (score 4):

That has more to do with the process [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) than with where the script is. For example, you have a script called `cat.py` like:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp:
    print fp.read()
```

and then you do:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ echo 12345 > test.txt
$ python /path/to/cat.py test.txt
12345
```

This will work as expected regardless of the script location, since the working directory is `/tmp` and the script doesn't change it.

Answer (score -1):

It's a relative path. So, you can put only filename if you run script in the same directory.

Comment: What happens if I change my working directory in the script with `os.chdir`?